# Meteor collection updated on server, not reflecting on client

Tags: meteor

I am trying to create a Meteor app that stores content in a Meteor collection to be passed between the server and the client to display a success message after an asynchronous api call through the twit package.

However, I am running into an issue where when I update the collection on the server and the updates are not reflected on the client. My code is as follows:

**/lib**

```
Alerts = new Meteor.Collection("alerts");
```

**/client**

```
Template.suggestionForm.events({
    "submit form": function (e) {
       return Meteor.call('submitMessage', message);
    }
 });
Meteor.subscribe('alerts');
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        console.log(Alerts.find());
    })
});
```

**/server**

```
Fiber = Npm.require('fibers')
Twit = new TwitMaker({
    consumer_key: '...',
    consumer_secret: '...',
    access_token: '...',
    access_token_secret: '...'
});
Meteor.publish("alerts", function(){
    Alerts.find();
});
Meteor.methods({
    submitMessage: function(message) {
        this.unblock();
        Twit.post('statuses/update', { 'status': message }, function(err, data, response) {
            Fiber(
                Alerts.remove({});
                Alerts.insert({response: err});
            ).run();
        }));
    }
});
```

When I submit the form the function calls just fine and updates the collection, however the Tracker.autorun() does not run. Any ideas why this is happening or how I can make the client listen for changes in collections would be super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to return the resulting cursor in the publish():

```
Meteor.publish("alerts", function(){
  return Alerts.find();
});
```

Reference: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish

> Publish functions can return a Collection.Cursor, in which case Meteor will publish that cursor's documents to each subscribed client. You can also return an array of Collection.Cursors, in which case Meteor will publish all of the cursors.

and

> Alternatively, a publish function can directly control its published record set by calling the functions added (to add a new document to the published record set), changed (to change or clear some fields on a document already in the published record set), and removed (to remove documents from the published record set). These methods are provided by this in your publish function.
>
> If a publish function does not return a cursor or array of cursors, it is assumed to be using the low-level added/changed/removed interface, and it must also call ready once the initial record set is complete.

Comment: I have never felt so dumb. Thank you!